# How to get bar chart width in pixel

Tags: javascript, chart.js

i am using chartjs lastest version (2.6.0). I just have a simple question that I want to get each bar width but i can not find the answer anywhere. Could someone please help me. Thanks alot. Here is simple bar chart.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="canvasChart" id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get each bar­*'s* width *(basically the same)* in ChartJS, using [**`.getDatasetMeta()`**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getdatasetmetaindex) method.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
         label: '# of Votes',
         data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});

function getWidth() {
   var barWidth = myChart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0]._view.width;
   alert(barWidth);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="getWidth()">Get Bar Width</button>
<canvas class="canvasChart" id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Cool. I found in chartjs doc but it just have method using guid, does not have return value detailed. Is there any doc write about it?

Comment: NVM. Thank you very much!